# Effect of moon on ocean tides

Tags: chandra

It is well known that moon affects the ocean tides [1](https://sciencing.com/effects-moon-phases-ocean-tides-8435550.html),[2](https://www.timeanddate.com/astronomy/moon/tides.html) and the effect is more during new moon, full moon days.

Is this phenomenon mentioned anywhere in the scriptures?

Answer (score 4):

**Yes**

Mahabharata mentioned that the moon affects the tides of the ocean in the following passage

> "Sauti said. 'Then when the night had passed away and the sun had
> risen in the morning, O thou whose wealth is asceticism, the two
> sisters Kadru and Vinata, having laid a wager about slavery, went with
> haste and impatience to view the steed Uchchaishravas from a near
> point. On their way they saw the Ocean, that receptacle of waters,
> vast and deep, rolling and tremendously roaring, full of fishes large
> enough to swallow the whale, and abounding with huge makaras and
> creatures of various forms by thousands, and rendered inaccessible by
> the presence of other terrible, monster-shaped, dark, and fierce
> aquatic animals, abounding with tortoises and crocodiles, the mine of
> all kinds of gems, the home of Varuna (the water-God), the excellent
> and beautiful residence of the Nagas, the lord of all rivers, the
> abode of the subterranean fire, the friend (or asylum) of the Asuras,
> the terror of all creatures, the grand reservoir of water, and ever
> immutable.......................................... **Full of swelling
> billows caused by the waxing and waning of the moon** the parent of
> Vasudeva's great conch called Panchajanya, the great mine of gems, its
> waters were formerly disturbed in consequence of the agitation caused
> within them by the Lord Govinda of immeasurable prowess when he had
> assumed the form of a wild boar for raising the (submerged) Earth. ...................................................................................................................
> It is fathomless and without limits, vast and immeasurable, and the
> lord of rivers.
>
> [[Section XXI, Astika Parva, Adi Parva, The Mahabharata]](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01022.htm)

Comment: Waves are the movement of sea water towards the coast and back to the sea periodically caused by the wind.  Ocean currents are the movement of sea water that resembles a very wide river and has a regular circulation.  Tides are the rise and fall of sea level caused by the gravitational force of the sun and the moon's gravity.

Comment: @muhamadsofyanSanusi Thanks, updated.

Comment: Does the Hindu scriptures explain the tides caused by the moon's gravity?

Comment: @muhamadsofyanSanusi I encountered the above paragraph, there can be other mentions also. But, in general, scriptures may say the moon alone instead of moon's gravity.

Comment: hindu mythology about the tides?

Comment: The text says that the tides are caused by the rising and falling of the moon, whereas modern science says that the tides are due to the moon's gravity, not the moon's ups and downs.

Comment: @muhamadsofyanSanusi ...But Newton didn’t believe that space was affected by the objects in it. Einstein did. He theorized that a mass can prod space plenty. It can warp it, bend it, push it, or pull it. **Gravity was just a natural outcome of a mass’s existence in space**  (Einstein had, with his 1905 Special Theory of Relativity, added time as a fourth dimension to space, calling the result space-time. Large masses can also warp time by speeding it up or slowing it down). [reference](https://www.amnh.org/explore/videos/space/gravity-making-waves/newton-einstein-gravity)

Comment: The Mahabharata text says that the large waves or tides of sea water are caused by the rising and falling of the moon while modern science says that the tides are caused by the moon's gravity.

Comment: @muhamadsofyanSanusi please read the comment above and its content if you are familiar with Physics.

Answer (score 3):

> In all the oceans the water remains at all times the same in quantity, and never, increases or diminishes; but like the water in a caldron, which, in consequence of its combination with heat, expands, **so the waters of the ocean swell with the increase of the moon. The waters, although really neither more nor less, dilate or contract as the moon increases or wanes in the light and dark fortnights.** The rise and fall of the waters of the different seas is five hundred and ten inches.

> **[Vishnu Purana 2:4:89](https://sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp062.htm)**

Comment: https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp062.htm

Comment: Please explain the concept of tides according to Hindu scriptures and Hindu mythology

Comment: Vayu Purana:
 129. The rise and fall of water in a fixed amount, no more and no less in the two weeks of light and dark at the rising and setting of the moon.  The rising and falling of the seas is the result of the rising and falling of the moon.